# como devolver la diferencia entre un producto de digitos y una suma de digitos

Tags: javascript

que tal. Estoy realizando este ejercicio donde debo devolver la resta entre el producto de una serie de digitos y la suma de esos mismos digitos.

```
var subtractProductAndSum = function(n) {
  var conver = n.toString();
var numero = conver.split('');
var mult = numero.reduce((a,b) => a * b);
var sum = numero.reduce ((a,b) => a + b);
    return mult - sum;
};
```

Tomando n = 234
me da una respuesta de -210  cuando deberia ser 15

Answer (score 0):

Cambia la línea donde declaras `var numero = conver.split('');` por:

```
var numero = conver.split('').map(n => Number.parseInt(n))
```

Tu problema es que estás haciendo los `reduce` con `Strings`, no con `Numbers`, por eso te da esos resultados inesperados. Con este `map`, conviertes todos los números de la cadena a `Number` y operas con ellos.

Puedes probar tu código acá:

```js
var subtractProductAndSum = function(n) {
    var conver = n.toString();
    var numero = conver.split('').map(n => Number.parseInt(n));
    var mult = numero.reduce((a,b) => a * b);
    var sum = numero.reduce ((a,b) => a + b);
    return mult - sum;
};

console.log(`subtractProductAndSum('234') = ${subtractProductAndSum('234')}`)
```